# Absolutely must or absolutely should?

Tags: adjectives

There's a problem I don't understand why I can't use **absolutely should** according to the book (Oxford Grammar Intermediate by Swan). Anyway, here's the problem:

> **Put in the best word: must or should**
>
> You absolutely (must/should) check the tyres before you take the car
> out today.

The key answer is **must**.

What I've known, **must** is stronger than **should**. The problem is, if we put an adjective behind either of them which makes it stronger, do they still have a difference?

By the way, I've checked the usage of both of these phrases [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Absolutely%20must%2C%20absolutely%20should&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAbsolutely%20must%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabsolutely%20should%3B%2Cc0). For the convenient reason, here's the screenshot of the diagram:

[image]

As you can see there, **absolutely should** is more common than **absolutely must**. Does that mean, the book is incorrect? I mean, the answer should be both are correct. No?

Comment: It's possible Swan is being a bit prescriptivist there. I hate to disagree with him, but in my opinion the answer absolutely should be that both are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NGram graph contains a small but very important mistake. You spelt absolutely with a capital A for must, but not for should. If you make both instances of absolutely begin with a lowercase a, you get [a completely different story](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=absolutely%20must%2Cabsolutely%20should&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabsolutely%20must%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabsolutely%20should%3B%2Cc0).

**[must](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/must)** implies a strong obligation, and **absolutely must** changes it to an unbreakable obligation.

**[should](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should)** is more of a suggestion- the correct thing to do, though there is no obligation at all to do the correct thing. **absolutely should** converts it to... an unbreakable suggestion?

I don't think there is anything grammatically wrong with **absolutely should** and, as the NGram graphs show, it is used but, in my opinion, there is a semantic problem: absolutely doesn't really fit with a suggestion. You can say that something is absolutely black, but I don't think you can say something is absolutely grey.